# ¿Cómo pasar un arreglo vacío por ajax en php?

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

Cree este arreglo que es para almacenar direcciones:

```
var arreglo_direcciones = [];
```

Este arreglo como ya mencione es para almacenar direcciones en otra función que tengo desarrollada y funciona perfectamente, pero a la hora de programar la función principal de mi formulario me di cuenta que tenia que validar que las direcciones son requeridas y ahí es donde viene el problema, cuando paso el arreglo `arreglo_direcciones` vacío por `ajax` este no pasa al lado de la controller pero si el este arreglo contiene elementos almacenados ahí si se pasa a la controller y le puedo hacer cualquier tratamiento a este arreglo. la declaracion de mi funcion principal de ajax es la siguiente:

```
$('#guardar-formulario').click(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();    

    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'{{ route('regMiembros.store') }}',
        data:{ arreglo_direcciones: arreglo_direcciones },

        success:function(data){

            if($.isEmptyObject(data.errors)){

                $.smkAlert({
                    text: data.success,
                    type:'success'
                });

                limpiarErrores();   


            } else {

                limpiarErrores();

                $.each(data.errors, function (index, value) {
                    $('#_'+index).text(value);
                });

                $.smkAlert({
                    text: "Existen errores de validacion, por favor revise ",
                    type:'danger'
                });
            }
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alerta(jqXHR.responseText);
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Hola que tal, y has probado del lado del controlador en php colocando un isset($arreglo)  para saber si esa variable viene, sino viene es porque está vacía y puedes realizar la validación que necesites.

Comment: si revise en el inspector de elementos de mi navegador si se pasa para el controller y cuando esta vacia es como si jquery lo eliminara pero cuando esta con algun elemento lo pasa y mi controller lo recibe y se realizan otras validaciones

Comment: por esa razón prueba colocando en tu controller un isset y puedes identificar si el ajax envió o no el arreglo si no lo envió realizas tu validación y si lo envió es porque si contiene información,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Intenta modificar los datos enviados en tu ajax de esta manera:

```
data:{ arreglo_direcciones: arreglo_direcciones.length ? arreglo_direcciones : null },
```

Y en el validador o en las reglas de validación de tu controladora verifica que el valor sea requerido, deberia funcionar.

Revisa este post [POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397669/jquery-ajax-jsonp-how-to-actually-send-an-array-even-if-its-empty) en la respuesta explican bien porque jquery no pasa el arreglo vacio.

Answer (score 3):

Hola la forma que se me ocurre es que en tu controlador coloques un isset como en el siguiente código:

```
if( !isset( $POST['arreglo'] ) )
{
 // Realizas validación que el arreglo no vino, por lo tanto el ajax lo envió vacio
}
```

O también lo puedes validar desde el lado del ajax, verificando que tu arreglo no se encuentre vació. Espero haya sido de ayuda.

Answer (score 2):

Primero procura capturar los posibles escenarios y asi sabras que camino lleva el hilo de ejecucion...

```
  // con isset preguntas se la variable esta seteada (si llego)
if( isset( $POST['arreglo_direcciones'] ) )
{
 // aqui haces algo si llego
        // !empty veirificas que no este vacia
    if( !empty( $POST['arreglo_direcciones'] ) )
    {
     // aqui haces algo si tiene algun valor
    }else{
        echo "La variable ESTA VACIA"
    }
}else{
    echo "La variable NO LLEGO";
}
```

espero te sirve Bro... ReNiceCode...